# Bootstrap nav-justified doesn't take up full width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav, justify

In [bootstrap-4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) there's a class for `nav-pill` links to have equal width and to take up all horizontal space:

> For equal-width elements, use `.nav-justified`. All horizontal space will be occupied by nav links.

At least that's what they say here: [Bootstrap: *Fill and justify*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#fill-and-justify)

This is their code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
   <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Longer nav link</a>
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
   <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```

which doesn't seem to work properly...

Am I missing or misunderstood something?

***Edit:***
Let me rephrase my question:
I understand what `.nav-fill` does.
I want to **understand** what `.nav-justified` does and why isn't working as they say.

Comment: what's the behavior that you get?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify my "problem".

Comment: You might want to upgrade Bootstrap to stable.

Comment: @Klooven I've tried both 4.0 and 4.1, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add one more class nav-item

```
<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
   <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item" href="#">Longer nav link</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item" href="#">Link</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```

Working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0c70csLt/)

Answer (score 3):

Add `nav-fill` class to `nav` element. `.nav-justified` use give same width link.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h6>Using nav-fill (to achive dynamic width link as link content</h6>
<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
   <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item" href="#">Longer nav link</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item" href="#">Link</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>
<h6>Using nav-fill and nav-justified (to achive same width link)</h6>
<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill nav-justified">
   <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item" href="#">Longer nav link</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item" href="#">Link</a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-item disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```

or if you want you can do this without bootstrap. for better understanding.

```css
.custom-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.custom-nav a {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* this line do all magic */ 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="custom-nav">
       <a  href="#">Active</a>
       <a  href="#">Longer nav link</a>
       <a  href="#">Link</a>
       <a  href="#">Disabled</a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow bootstrap `html` structure to achieve this. you need to wrap `a` tags in `li` and give those `li` class `nav-item` within `ul`, and give that `ul` classes `nav nav-pills nav-fill`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Longer nav link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tbfjbw98/1/)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)